# Android update listview while loading

Tags: android, android-listview

I am receiving data from a restapi call and these data are then stored in the ormlite db. How can I download these data and update the listview at the same time?
For example.
A B C D E F G are data to be downloaded through restapi call

A B C was downloaded and shows on listview.
at the same time the api call keeps downloadin the rest of the data
when D E F G are downloaded. It shows on listview automatically.
This stops when there's nothing to download anymore.

Comment: Since you wrote nothing about your adapter we cannot give you an answer. You just wrote your requirements and not what you have tried and where you have failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Do your loading of data in a background thread.
2. Depending upon your preference, either every xxx minutes or after xxx amount of data loaded, callback a method (say update() ) in your adapter.
3. in your update() method, perform any of the data specific changes that you want to make like lets say you might want to hide some textview if data A is present. Once data specific things are handled, call notifyDataSetChanged(). This will refresh your listview.